# c# String textbox text in a command line

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# do bear with my horrible flaws. :P

So I want my button to ping a site using basic command lines but for some reason it doesn't want to print it on the command line.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URL = textBox1.Text;

        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "ping" + URL;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```

The textBox1's text contains the sites url that in this case it was "www.google.com"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMSz.jpg

I have seen many different methods to this but not one of them is near anything I want to do in this case.

thanks :)

Comment: There is a white space missed after ping. You need `"ping "`

Comment: Also, `cmd` doesn't take parameters like that.  You want `/k`

Comment: Don't you also need the `/c` switch in front of the command you want to run? (The /k switch suggested above will not terminate the console window after the program is done executing)

Answer (score 5):

You might also look at the [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) if you don't want to use the command line.

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(URL);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string strCmdText = "/c ping " + URL;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Comment: The OP is going to have a slight dilemma in that /C will close his cmd window, possibly before he looks at the information he wants, and the /K switch will open a new cmd window each time the method is run.

Comment: thanks! , the /C must have slipped my mind forgetting that :)